# Sorting in listview with object data source

Tags: sorting, listview, asp.net-3.5, objectdatasource

net web application for social networking.
I am using VS2008 and sqlserver 2008[.net 3.5]

In this website we are using 3-tier architecture. We pass businessobject to the UI.

My listview is binded with object data source. Now I want to implement sorting in listview.
Can anyone please suggest me the best method to do sorting in ListView with Object data source

Answer (score 1):

Add a parameter to the method of your business layer that gives you the data. This parameter will tell it how to sort the collection.

The ObjectDataSource object support [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.sortparametername.aspx) to set the member on which the sort must be done.